# jQUery Dialog Box when Clicking Navigation Bar Link not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up a jQuery Dialog box from clicking a list element in my navigation bar. I have the code working for a separate project when clicking a canvas element but it wont work for this application. My code is as follows:

Clickable Div in Nav-Bar List:

```
<nav id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="fancypdf" href="img/resume.pdf">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a>Youtube</a></li>
        <li class="contact" style="cursor:pointer;">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Div that Should Show up in Dialog Box:

```
<div class='dialog'>
    Hello
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".contact").click(function(event){
        $(".dialog").dialog({
            width:490,
            height:500,
            draggable:false,
            blur:true,
            show:{
                effect:"blind",
                duration:100
                },
    hide: {
    effect: 'blind',
    duration: 100
    }
        });
});
});
</script>
```

My "imports":
    http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/fancybox-2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.pack.js">    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
```

Here is all of my main script tags:

```
<script>
$(".fancypdf").click(function(){
$.fancybox({
type: 'html',
autoSize: false,
content: '<embed src="'+this.href+'#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=80,0,0"    type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />',
beforeClose: function() {
$(".fancybox-inner").unwrap();
}
}); //fancybox
return false;
}); //click
</script>


<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, fall back to local if offline -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-  1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');</script>


<!-- FancyBox -->
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
beforeShow : function(){
this.title =  this.title + " - " + $(this.element).data("caption");
}
});
}); // ready
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
maxWidth    : 800,
maxHeight   : 600,
fitToView   : false,
width   : '70%',
height  : '70%',
autoSize    : false,
closeClick  : false,
openEffect  : 'elastic',
closeEffect : 'none',
beforeShow : function(){
this.title =  $(this.element).data("caption");
}
});
});
</script>

<script>
var jquery = jQuery.noConflict();
jquery(function(){
jquery(".contact").click(function(event){
console.log("clicked");
jquery(".dialog").dialog({
width:490,
height:500,
draggable:false,
blur:true,
show:{
effect:"blind",
duration:100
},
hide: {
effect: 'blind',
duration: 100
}
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine.. just make sure the js are loaded properly.. check http://jsbin.com/pinifi/1/edit for demo

Comment: i am clicking the link for resume and it's going to something that states: "You're page is not here."

Comment: I added what I have loaded.

Comment: you have binded the click event only for "contact" link not for resume linke that's why its taking you to different page

Comment: ah I see but its still not working for me, I copied your code in a separate project and it works there too. It's not my computer, do you think it could be what I've loaded up? Could the loading of the fancybox files be messing with my jQuery loads?

Comment: share the code you have added for fancybox.

Comment: Even after i have included fancybox code its working fine http://jsbin.com/pinifi/1/edit , i guess how you are linking fancybox to the resume link makes the difference

Comment: check this link : http://jsbin.com/nopid/3/edit it works but still eratically because of conflict

Comment: yea with the latest jsbin link, it doesn't work. It's doing exactly what its doing on my end which is absolutely anything. So I guess the conflict will prevent me from using fancybox for pdfs and dialog boxes

Comment: Why don't you just use fancybox to handle dialog boxes also??

Comment: I was thinking about doing that actually. I will give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: see now I'm stuck with this. Do I have to create an image for fancybox that has the word "hello" because fancybox seems to keep asking for a file.

Comment: great! enjoy :) hope now you can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include jQuery UI or the order of jQuery and jQuery UI loaded are wrong.

Your code is working fine.

[**Tested in jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/pinifi/1/edit)

Just make sure all js are included properly:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```